# Почему в браузере выдается набор символов?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, кодировка, mysql

Здравствуйте!

У меня проблемы с базой данных. Импортировала базу на хостинг, указала кодировку и при создании пользователя и при импорте: `cp1251_bin`. В панели управления майадмина все в порядке, а в браузере выдается набор символов.

В чем может быть проблема? Кодировка сайта и базы данных `windows 1251`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно всегда использую

```
cp1251_general_ci
```

Попробуйте в скрипте, после коннекта к БД выполнить что-то типа этого:

```
mysql_query('set names cp1251');
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! всего одна строчка и все получилось! а я как только не пробовала уже!